# Method of setting the way a button functions when using Controls.Add(new button(){}) in a loop

Tags: c#, winforms, loops, button

I'm currently designing a WinForms music player and I'm having some trouble figuring out how to set what a button does when the button is created via

```
Controls.Add(new Button(){})
```

The code I'm currently using is a while loop inside of which is the code to create a button name  + x where x is a value that increments at the end of the loop. What i would like to do is set it so that on click the button will execute the function to play music which is named say "mpPlay". What would be the best way to go about this?

Here is the current code I'm using:

```
while (trackNoReader.Read())
{
    flpTrackNo.Controls.Add(new Button()
    {
        Name = "btnTrackNo" + x,
        Text = trackNoReader[0] as string,
        BackColor = Color.Transparent,
        FlatStyle = FlatStyle.Flat,
        AutoSize = false,
        Dock = DockStyle.Top,
        Width = flpArtist.Width,
        ForeColor = ColorTranslator.FromHtml("#444444"),
        Font = new Font("Trebuchet MS", 9),
        Enabled = true,
        TextAlign = ContentAlignment.MiddleLeft,
        FlatAppearance =
        {
            BorderSize = 0
        },
    });

    x++;
}
```

If you wish to see the source code you can download the git repository [here](https://github.com/Rossosaurus/KEVINMusicPlayer). Many Thanks - Ross
[EDIT]

Here's the code for mpPlay()

```
public void mpPlay(int x, string Column)
    {
        MySqlCommand selectPath = new MySqlCommand("SELECT" + Column + "FROM Music WHERE TrackNo=" + x);
        selectPath.Connection = DB.connect;
        MySqlDataReader readerPath = selectPath.ExecuteReader();
        while (readerPath.Read())
        {
            path = readerPath[0] as string;
            path = path.Replace("\"", "\\");
        }
        mpPlayer.Open(path);
        mpPlayer.Play();
    }
```

Comment: Your button doesn't do anything, other than sitting pretty in that panel.  You can bang that button as hard as you can but without a Click event handler nothing will ever happen.  Never hesitate to derive your own class from Button, override OnClick to do something useful and add whatever properties you need to get it to do something useful.  That collapses this code to a one-liner.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could have a simple helper method like this:

```
public Button AttachMethodToButton(Button b, Action buttonMethod)
{
    b.Click += (s, e) => buttonMethod();
    return b;
}
```

which you would call like this:

```
flpTrackNo.Controls.Add(AttachMethodToButton(new Button()
    {
        // ... button properties like you already have
    }, 
    mpPlay));  // I'm assuming 'mpPlay' is a void method
```

If you want to call `mpPlay` with arguments, you'd call it like this:

```
flpTrackNo.Controls.Add(AttachMethodToButton(new Button()
    {
        // ... button properties like you already have
    }, 
    () => mpPlay(intParam, stringParam))); // replace intParam and stringParam with whatever arguments you want here
```

Comment: Hi there, when i use mpPlay as a void and run the program it returns an error saying cannot convert void to system.Action and when i use mpPlay as an action i get an error saying not all code paths return an error. Ive put an edit with the code i use for mpPlay. Any ideas on how to fix this? Many Thanks - Ross

Comment: @RossUnderhill I added an example of how you could call `mpPlay` with arguments.

Comment: Hi again, unfortunately i still can't get this to work currently when the button is created the button is grayed out like if it was disabled however when add Enabled = true, to the controls.add it still doesn't enable it. Should the object s and eventarg e in AttachMethodToButton be replaced with something else in my program. Sorry if this is a really simple fix and/or a stupid question I'm new'ish to VisualStudio. Thanks - Ross

Answer (score 0):

```
while (trackNoReader.Read())
{
    flpTrackNo.Controls.Add(new Button()
    {
        Name = "btnTrackNo" + x,
        Text = trackNoReader[0] as string,
        BackColor = Color.Transparent,
        FlatStyle = FlatStyle.Flat,
        AutoSize = false,
        Dock = DockStyle.Top,
        Width = flpArtist.Width,
        ForeColor = ColorTranslator.FromHtml("#444444"),
        Font = new Font("Trebuchet MS", 9),
        Enabled = true,
        TextAlign = ContentAlignment.MiddleLeft,
        FlatAppearance =
        {
            BorderSize = 0
        },
    });

    // Adds Click event handler to last added button
    flpTrackNo.Controls[flpTrackNo.Controls.Count - 1].Click += (sender, args) =>
    {
        // Call the function to play a sound

        // Additionally the sender gives you the specific button as object
    };

    x++;
}
```